# Imprimir Impressora Bluetooth ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, bluetooth, impressora

Alguém conseguiu de fato imprimir em impressora bluetooth usando Ionic, cordova, phonegap algum método que não foi nativo?

Meu projeto foi escrito em Ionic, logo surgiu essa necessidade :(

Comment: teve algum progresso na impressão bluetooth com desenvolvimento híbrido?